# Callback error updating output-link.href - Parsing and downloading CSV file

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

Aim and objective: I am beginner to web development and I'm using plotly Dash to allow user to upload a CSV file, run a script to modify the CSV file and let the user download the the modified CSV file.

Tools employed: I am using dash.core.components to achieve this. I use dcc.upload to allow the user to upload a file and using html.A to return a link to the modified csv file which allows the user to download the file. All modifications to csv file performed using Pandas.

Issue: However, when I'm trying to return the href for the modified file, I run into a callback error.

Code Description: For reference in the below code, the function interval_cleaner reads the csv file, identifies missing data and fills the missing data.The interval_cleaner basically takes the contents component of dcc.upload as an input and decodes the contents and returns a dataframe. In the callback function "update_output_parser", I call the interval_cleaner function which returns a pandas dataframe (clean_dat) which is then converted to a csv file which I'm trying to return as the href component of html.A.

Data: I have 21886 rows in the original file but output is around 17520 rows.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Date':[7/1/2019 0:30,7/1/2019 1:00,7/1/2019 1:30,7/1/2019 2:00],'Demand':[60.48,52.92,49.32,53.28]})
```

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import urllib
import base64
import io

app=dash.Dash()

app.layout=html.Div([
    html.H3('Unit of the data'),
    dcc.RadioItems(
        id='units',
        options=[{'label':'kWh','value':'kwh'},
                 {'label':'kW','value':'kw'}],
        value='kwh',
        labelStyle={'display':'inline-block'}
        ),
    html.H3('Interval of load data'),
    dcc.RadioItems(
        id='intervals',
        options=[{'label':'15 minutes','value':15},
                 {'label':'30 minutes','value':30},
                 {'label':'Hourly','value':60}],
        value=60,
        labelStyle={'display':'inline-block'}
        ),
    html.H3('Convert into other intervals'),
    dcc.RadioItems(
        id='conversion',
        options=[{'label':'Yes','value':'y'},
                 {'label':'No','value':'n'}],
        value='n',
        labelStyle={'display':'inline-block'}
        ),
    dcc.Upload(
        id='upload-data',
        children=html.Div([
            'Drag and Drop or ',
            html.A('Select Files')
        ]),
        style={
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '60px',
            'lineHeight': '60px',
            'borderWidth': '1px',
            'borderStyle': 'dashed',
            'borderRadius': '5px',
            'textAlign': 'center',
            'margin': '10px'
        },
        # Allow multiple files to be uploaded
        multiple=True
    ),
    html.Div(id='Filename'),
    html.A('Download cleaned load',id='output-link',download='cleaned_load_data.csv',target='_blank'),
    ])

def interval_cleaner(csv_file_content,unit,frequency):
    content_type, content_string = csv_file_content.split(',')
    decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')))
    df['Date']=df['Date'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
    df=df.set_index('Date').sort_index()
    if frequency==15:
        mult=4
    elif frequency==30:
        mult=2
    else:
        mult=1
    cleaned_load=pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start=df.index[0], end=df.index[0]+pd.to_timedelta('364 days 23:59:00'),freq=str(frequency)+'T'),columns=['Date']) #365 days changed to 364 days
    leap=len(cleaned_load[((cleaned_load['Date'].dt.month==2) & (cleaned_load['Date'].dt.day==29))])
    if leap!=0:
        cleaned_load=cleaned_load[~((cleaned_load['Date'].dt.month==2) & (cleaned_load['Date'].dt.day==29))]
        if frequency==60:
            cleaned_load=cleaned_load.append(pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(cleaned_load.iloc[len(cleaned_load)-1,0]+pd.to_timedelta('01:00:00'),cleaned_load.iloc[len(cleaned_load)-1,0]+pd.to_timedelta('1 day'),freq=str(frequency)+'T'),columns=['Date']),ignore_index=True)
        else:
            cleaned_load=cleaned_load.append(pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(cleaned_load.iloc[len(cleaned_load)-1,0]+pd.DateOffset(minute=frequency),cleaned_load.iloc[len(cleaned_load)-1,0]+pd.to_timedelta('1 day'),freq=str(frequency)+'T'),columns=['Date']),ignore_index=True)    
    cleaned_load=cleaned_load.set_index('Date')
    cleaned_load=cleaned_load.join(df,how='left')
    cleaned_load=cleaned_load[~cleaned_load.index.duplicated(keep='last')].reset_index()
    #print(cleaned_load.head())
    cleaned_load['MDH']=cleaned_load['Date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d %H:%M')
    nans=cleaned_load[cleaned_load['Demand'].isnull()].index
    #print(nans)
    #print(cleaned_load.iloc[nans,0])
    for item in nans:
        if item<24*mult*7:
            ind=cleaned_load.iloc[item:len(cleaned_load)+item:24*mult,1].first_valid_index()  # 70 day changed to len() 
            cleaned_load.iloc[item,1]=cleaned_load.iloc[ind:ind+24*mult*7:24*mult,1].mean(skipna=True)
        else:
            cleaned_load.iloc[item,1]=cleaned_load.iloc[item-24*mult*7:item:24*mult,1].mean(skipna=True)
    cleaned_load=cleaned_load.sort_values(by='MDH')
    return cleaned_load

@app.callback(Output('output-link', 'href'),
              Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
              [State('units', 'value'),
              State('intervals', 'value')])
def update_output_parser(file_contents,unit,frequency):
    clean_dat=interval_cleaner(file_contents,unit,frequency)
    dat_csv=clean_dat.to_csv(encoding='utf-8')
    dat_csv = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + urllib.quote(dat_csv)
    return dat_csv


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: What is the exact callback error you are receiving, please add it to your code so that we can better address your problem.

Comment: I managed to figure it out. I didn't realize the contents component of dcc.upload was a list and I needed extract the element inside the list. Basically, changing file_contents to file_contents[0] solved my issue.